# java memory-leak. how to break reachability of objcts & how to minimize clone method?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I am working on a java web start application which is suffering from memory leak. I used many tools and find the suspicious objects. And my application used many object's clone method. Now the problem is how to fix it.... Putting null to objects when it is lastly used is not working..... Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: Sorry,I am not supposed to paste code anywhere as it will become an integrity issue. At many place clone were used like Object.clone() and somewhere it's super clone(). Actually many people said to break reachability of objects....Could anyone please explain it as i don't have any idea regarding this.... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Fire up [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) it should allow you to see what objects are hanging around. Its an invaluable tool for debugging memory related issues.

Comment: @ Paul Whelan I am able to find the objects that is creating problem means that is retaining reference. If i am putting it null then also same thing it's retaining the reference. Is there any other way apart from putting null???

Comment: @Hriday Every strong refernece has to be released, if you have even one left, the object is retained.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Actually i am facing problem to release the strong reference. Could you please explain how to do that? Kindly give one example....Thanks in Advance

Comment: @PaulWhelan Could yu please explain how to see those objects? Actually i am able to see only the classes which has appearance in jvm through Visual VM.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks happen when you have a long running process that holds references to objects that should have disappeared.

For example, I found that closed documents in a Swing application were held in memory because there were keyboard and mouse listeners (global to the application) that were still holding references to the panel showing them.

As said above, JVisualVM can help in finding the root of the retained objects, through a chain of references. Find the root, cut the link there.

If your clone methods keep references / share objects with the original object, it means your clones are badly coded (they are supposed to do deep copy, AFAIK). See the Effective Java book for proper clone() writing (or use alternatives, like copy constructors).